# Stopping Bukkit Loops and Logging When a Horse Dies in Bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

today I was trying to make a plugin that spawns a skeletal horse and fire particles are around the horse. I got that part down but however whenever someone kills the bone horse the fire particles stay there. Somebody please help?

Also My Code (2 Classes):

```
package survivalcraft.FireHorse;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Horse.Variant;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.entity.Horse;
import org.bukkit.inventory.HorseInventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
public static Main plugin;
public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");

@Override
public void onDisable(){
    PluginDescriptionFile pdf = this.getDescription();
    this.logger.info(pdf.getName() + " version " + pdf.getVersion() + " has been disabled! Neigh! ;D");
}

@Override
public void onEnable(){
    PluginDescriptionFile pdf = this.getDescription();
    this.logger.info(pdf.getName() + " version " + pdf.getVersion() + " has been enabled! Neigh! ;D");
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if(sender instanceof Player){
        if(player.hasPermission("firehorse.spawn")){
            if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("firehorse") || commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("fh")){
                if(args.length == 0){
                    Horse horse = (Horse) player.getWorld().spawnEntity(player.getLocation(), EntityType.HORSE);
                    HorseInventory horseinv = null;
                    ItemStack saddle = new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE);
                    horse.setVariant(Variant.SKELETON_HORSE);
                    horse.setCustomName(player.getDisplayName() + "'s Fire Horse");                     
                    horse.setTamed(true);
                    horseinv.setSaddle(saddle);
                    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new HorseTimer(horse), 0l, 5l);
                }else{
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Usage: /firehorse");
                }
            }
        }else{
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You can't spawn a fire horse!");
        }
    }else{
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must be a player in order to spawn a fire horse!");
    }   
    return false;
}   
}
```

2nd class:

```
package survivalcraft.FireHorse;

import org.bukkit.Effect;
import org.bukkit.entity.Horse;

public class HorseTimer implements Runnable{
private Horse horse;

public HorseTimer(Horse horse){
    this.horse = horse;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    horse.getWorld().playEffect(horse.getLocation(), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1st:
Check if a horse is alive like @Momo posted, with a small correction by @CrypticStorm

2nd:
Class HorseTimer should **extend** BukkitRunnable onstead of implementing Rumnable so it can cancel itself
see http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming#Self-Canceling_Example_2

Answer (score 1):

You should change `scheduleSyncRepeatingTask` to `runTaskTimer` since that is the proper method now. That returns an int representing its id which you can store then call `Bukkit.getScheduler().cancelTask(int id)` when you listen to the `EntityDeathEvent`.

Comment: scheduleSyncRepeatingTask  also returns an int which can be used for the task

Comment: Either way, you want the task id.

Comment: Why suggest changing it though?

Comment: EDIT: oops, mistaken context. I suggest changing it because the non-deprecated async methods no longer fall under the same naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for all the code but this should get the job done, it stores task id's and horse id's to use at a latter date to cancel tasks based on the horse death.

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
public static Main plugin;
public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");

@Override
public void onDisable(){
    PluginDescriptionFile pdf = this.getDescription();
    this.logger.info(pdf.getName() + " version " + pdf.getVersion() + " has been disabled! Neigh! ;D");
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}

@Override
public void onEnable(){
    PluginDescriptionFile pdf = this.getDescription();
    this.logger.info(pdf.getName() + " version " + pdf.getVersion() + " has been enabled! Neigh! ;D");
}

Map<UUID, Integer> tasks = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if(sender instanceof Player){
        if(player.hasPermission("firehorse.spawn")){
            if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("firehorse") || commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("fh")){
                if(args.length == 0){
                    Horse horse = (Horse) player.getWorld().spawnEntity(player.getLocation(), EntityType.HORSE);
                    HorseInventory horseinv = null;
                    ItemStack saddle = new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE);
                    horse.setVariant(Variant.SKELETON_HORSE);
                    horse.setCustomName(player.getDisplayName() + "'s Fire Horse");                     
                    horse.setTamed(true);
                    horseinv.setSaddle(saddle);
                    int id = Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new HorseTimer(horse), 0l, 5l);
                    tasks.put(horse.getUniqueId(), id);
                }else{
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Usage: /firehorse");
                }
            }
        }else{
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You can't spawn a fire horse!");
        }
    }else{
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must be a player in order to spawn a fire horse!");
    }   
    return false;
} 

    Map<UUID, Integer> map = null;
    @EventHandler
    public void handleDeaths(EntityDeathEvent event){
        for(UUID id : map.keySet())
            if(event.getEntity().getUniqueId().equals(id))
                Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(map.get(id));
    }

}
```

Comment: `Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");` is not guaranteed by future versions of Bukkit. You should be using `Plugin.getLogger()` for all logging done by your plugin.

Comment: I guess this ^ is for the op didn't do any logging myself when I edited

Comment: err, yea. I'm pretty off my game today. I thought you added that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this check in your run() method:

```
if (!horse.isDead()) {
    // Spawn particles
}
```

This will prevent spawning the particles to a dead horse.

Comment: Firstly the method is isAlive(). Second this does not cancel the runnable (bad). Third, the not canceled runnable contains a reference to an Entity preventing it from garbage collection. This is not the way to cancel the runnable properly.

Comment: @CrypticStorm
l know this question is old, but this is actually a good method.
You can simply do:
     if (horse.isAlive()) // do stuff
     else this.cancel();

Answer (score 0):

All the answers do their job, but not efficiently.

DeathEvent can be a busy place, especially with **mob farms**.

Here a better alternative to add into your `run()` method:

```
if (horse.isAlive()) {
    // spawn particles
} else {
    this.cancel();
}
```